# Cant select newly dynamically added elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello the issue that am having is that after using fetchAPI with a function to populate a table with data am creating a cell for every row that contains a Delete button for the user to click and am using js to create and append those cells buttons so after that i try to select those buttons with another function but nothing happens tried to use addEventlistener and load event and lastly DOMContentLoaded to check if the document is loaded to select those items but everytime i get an error

here is some parts of my code

```js
function fetchAllCategories(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let table = document.querySelector('#categories');
    fetch(`${url}category`, {
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json",
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
              },
          method: 'get',
      })
      .then((response) => response.json()) //
        .then((json) => {
          // console.log(json.data[0]);
          // -------------------------

          // Loop through the JSON data
          for (const object of json.data) {
            // Create a new row for the table
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
              // adding control buttons to the table
              const cellButton = document.createElement("td");
              const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
              removeButton.textContent = 'حذف';
              removeButton.className = 'btn btn-danger mt-3 format delete-btn';
              removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
              removeButton.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
              removeButton.setAttribute("data-bs-target", "#confimDelete");

              cellButton.appendChild(removeButton);

            // Add cells to the row for each property of the object
            for (const key in object) {
              const cell = document.createElement("td");
              cell.textContent = object[key];

              row.appendChild(cell);
              
            }

            // Append the remove button to the control cells 
            row.appendChild(cellButton);
            // Append the row to the table
            table.appendChild(row);
          }

          // -------------------------
        })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
}

// Get the NodeList of buttons
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-btn");

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('created successfully');
  });
  console.log('document loaded');
});
```

Comment: Please add HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]. You want to use delegation for this

Comment: The linked duplicate starts off very jQuery-heavy, which is a product of the time it was written.  But one of the near-top answers (and potentially more below it) doesn't use jQuery and is more generally applicable.  The root problem is the same... You can't bind a click event to an element that doesn't exist on the page at that time.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { const table = document.querySelector('#categories'); table.addEventListener('click', (e) => { const tgt = e.target.closest('.delete-btn'); if (!tgt) return; tgt.closest('tr').remove() }); });`